# HTML video attribute is not working on the react page

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, html5-video

So I'm just designing a basic portfolio where I want a video to be auto-played in loop in the div's background. So to do that I've made a couple of modifications here and there. Long story short, my video isn't showing up for some reasons. Let me know If you guys have any idea what is going on here.

**App.js** :

```
class App extends Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="startBackground">
              <video autoPlay muted loop>
                <source src="images/timelapse.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
              </video>
              <HeaderJumbotron/>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Header jumbotron is just another component which would contain the text I want to display over this background video. It would act as my caption class.

**index.css** :

```
.startBackground {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.startBackground video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  object-fit: cover;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

timelapse.mp4 is located inside the images folder which is inside the src folder. All the other files (index.js, app.js, index.css etc. are inside src itself). Any idea what I'm doing wrong here ? Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Place all your videos inside Public/Videos and then access it by:

```
<video autoPlay muted loop>
    <source src="/Videos/timelapse.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

And the issue gets resolved! :)

NOTE: Don't forget to add / in the start of the path.